# Change contentTintColor on mouseDown for NSButton

Tags: swift, appkit, nsbutton, nsevent, nscontrol

I have a custom button that subclasses NSButton. I want to change the content tint color when the button is in pressed state. This is what I have:

```
open override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    // update contentTintColor
    contentTintColor = contentTintColorPressed
    // call super to inherit the click action
    super.mouseDown(with: event)
    // for some reason mouseUp doesn't trigger if I call super, so I have to override and manually call mouseUp 
    self.mouseUp(with: event)
}
```

The result of this is the content tint color becomes the backgroundColor, so the button content is invisible. Why is that the contentTintColor updates only when I drag my cursor outside of the button? [demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8P6Hr.gif)

Answer (score -1):

Programmatically you can change like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Change button text color when tapping is on hold.
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .highlighted)
}
```

If you have custom UIButton class, use like this:

```
self.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .highlighted)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me since I'm using NSButton. I want to manipulate the title color using the contentTintColor attribute.

Comment: Hi Manchiu, let me know once you find an answer, would like to know how to do for NSButton.